# Find Files That Contain Exactly Two Forward Slashes

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I have a file that contains the output of a tar archive in the following format:

```
-rw-r--r-- me/users       362 2011-03-01 18:23 home/me/de/bin/aur/jdk/pkg/opt/java/lib/visualvm/platform/update_tracking/org-openide-awt.xml
```

What I am trying to output are only the filenames, and only the filenames that contain exactly 2 slashes, i.e. `home/me/filename.txt`.

I do not want `home/me/dir1/filename.txt`, or `home/me/dir1/dir2/filename.txt`

I am having difficulty because every file in the archive begins with `home/me/`

I have so far been trying using grep and awk but no luck. I know I can use cut to get the filenames once I get the list I want.

Comment: Filenames can't contain slashes (or nul bytes).

Comment: That's not a file name, it's a tar content list.

Comment: Why dont you use find command with maxdepth as 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWK can do it like:

```
 awk '{ orig=$NF ; if (gsub("/","",$NF) == 2) { print orig  } }' INPUTFILE
```

You can [see it in action here](http://ideone.com/GVQDVV).

Comment: Thanks so much.  Does exactly what I asked and I learned something too.

Comment: Just be aware it will fail for file names that contain spaces. If you have those let us know to get a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

I assume each line is the same fixed-width format, so

```
shopt -s extglob
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "${line:47}" == +([^/])/+([^/])/+([^/]) ]]; then
        # has 2 slashes
        echo "${line:47}"
    fi
done < filename
```

Answer (score 2):

@glennjackman gave me an idea for a robust awk solution that will work if file names contain spaces (and appear in a fixed location):

```
awk -F'^.{47}' 'gsub(/\//,"&",$2)==2{print $2}' file
```

and if you don't mind an extra "/" added to the front of the file path you can abbreviate to:

```
awk 'gsub(/^.{47}|\//,"/")==3' file
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that gsub removes those slashes in place. So if you want to print it later you should save the value earlier. But you can work around with matcing a gensub result string...

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai no it doesn't. try it.

Comment: It might depend on your gawk version @EdMorton, see here http://ideone.com/Yoz0ym

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai You're using an older gawk that doesn't have RE intervals enabled by default. Add the --re-interval flag.

Comment: No I'm not. Ideone is using an old one. And my workplace's server admin. And several other people in the world.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 's|^([^ ]* *){5}(([^/]*/){2}[^/]*)$|\2|p' file
```